# How to polyfill FormattedDate on SSR?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-intl

The problem is that FormattedDate from react-intl generates one content on SSR and another one on client side.

I took for example this project to demonstrate error:
https://github.com/weiliang903/react-intl-with-next

From SSR I'll get 'Tue, Oct 15' but on client side 'Tuesday, October 15'. What is the problem?

```
<FormattedDate
  value={new Date()}
  weekday="long"
  month="long"
  day="2-digit"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs from config for this function. You should provide only combinations described on this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) or function will use default config.